# Server Concurrency with High CPU Load

Tags: php, mysql, apache2, symfony-1.4, redhat

I've hosted a `php` application built on top of `symfony 1.4` on a dedicated server. The server (**apache on Redhat**) has a **4 core cpu, 32GB ram & a SSD**. In the application there is a `php` script (symfony task) that runs once a month and that task is heavy (it takes like 30 minutes to complete and it executes lots of mysql queries on the application's database). I observed that the response time increases significantly when the task is run. It gets worse when concurrency level is also high at the same time. `max-memory-limit` in `php.ini` is set to **4096MB** now.

***Is there a way to run the task without reducing the response time of concurrent request?*** It doesn't matter if the task take more time without affecting the response time. A hardware based solution, configuration based solution or architecture level solution is ok.

Comment: you could start it with low CPU and IO priority, read into nice and ionice for that - however ionice won't affect the database itself. you could also try scattering some sleep-command in the code to force arbitrary breaks every now and then. or try to split up the workload in smaller chunks, if possible-  and obviously run them when traffic is low

Comment: Is this dedicated server running both Apache and MySQL?

Comment: @KrisPeeling yes. both are there